# how split a string and assign a unique id

Tags: java, string

I want to read a input file and convert the sentence in to words and then provide a unique integer id.

I was able to  convert the input string in to words but i'm confused how to assign unique ids for each word and need to remove duplicates. (if input - i want to go to kandy. both occasions 'to' should  get same id   )

This is my code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter the word");

String s= sc.nextLine();
String st[] =s.split(" ");
   for(int i=0;i<st.length-1 ;i++)
   {
        System.out.println(st[i]);
   }
```

Comment: Side note, `i<st.length-1` should be `i<st.length` if you want to print all elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UUID and HashMap for this purpose:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); // storage for all word-id pairs

/* here insert your resulting array from scanner and split as collectionOfWords */
for (String yourNextWord : collectionOfWords) {

String id = UUID.randomUUID();      // this one generates a unique string id
map.put(yourNextWord, id);

}
```

In the process, hashmap replaces duplicates as keys, so you will always have 1 and the same entry for many copies of 1 word. Thus, their ids will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        HashMap<Integer, String> store = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

        System.out.println("enter the word");

        String s= sc.nextLine();
        String st[] =s.split(" ");
        Integer uniqueId=1;

        for(int i=0;i<st.length;i++)
        {
            if(!store.values().contains(st[i])){
                store.put(uniqueId, st[i] );
                uniqueId = uniqueId+1;
            }                               
         }

         for (Integer id: store.keySet()){
             String key =id.toString();
             String value = store.get(id).toString();  
             System.out.println(key + " " + value);  

            }
         sc.close();
        }   

    }
```